# Select in calendar with concat and between

Tags: mysql, concatenation, between

I got a table called calendar, in that table I have this rows:
-day
-month
-year

why? Because I need it  hehe.

So, the problem is when I want search a date in diferent year ( in the same year it's ok), for example:

Days between: 31-12-2013 and 1-1-2014, so I have a query:

**SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE concat(year,'-',month,'-',day)  BETWEEN '2013-1-30' AND '2013-1-31';**

But, this query search in the same year and show the another months (I have in my db the 730 days) and not the 2014.

So, I'm confused because, how can I concat the rows and search with between?
Hope you can help me to understand, and sorry for my english.

Thanks for all.!!

Comment: it depends on the type of data you put ! Date or String !

Comment: Can you expand on your question ?  You want to search 'date in different year' ?  One date, a range of dates ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT * FROM calendar 
WHERE str_to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-',day),'%Y-%m-%d') 
          BETWEEN '2013-1-30' AND '2013-1-31';
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7e76/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, and it works!, but as I comment, when I run the query, this show the another months too (show the info that i need too), and how can I say to my query that i don't want to see the another months.

Comment: @SundayGirl. This can't be showing the other months. You must have some weird thing outside this query messing with your results. Can you show your table in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com), to see what it is doing?

Comment: @SundayGirl. See this fiddle to see it working between two years: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbac06/1

Comment: I know it's weird, because I edit the values in the sql fiddle, and show the results as I need it, but in my mysql local the result is different. Let me do some tests, and tell you what happen. 
Thanks!!

Comment: Haha, I don't know what happen, but my mysql local works finally!! Thanks for all!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day)) BETWEEN '2013-1-30' AND '2013-1-31';
```

I'm also curious as to why you 'need' to store year, month and day as three seperate fields, and not in a single date field?

I think year, month and day may also be reserved keywords in mysql, so you may have to do

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE DATE(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-',`day`)) BETWEEN '2013-1-30' AND '2013-1-31';
```

Comment: Thank you, and as I comment when I search in the same year, it works, but in diferent year the result is different, I mean, show the result that I need, but also shows another months that is innecesary.
But thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you post the data you are using? My code should work (as does Filipe Silva's)